# Angular Material | How can change datapicker output format?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use Angular material datapicker but ı want to change dataPicker output.

This is output : Wed Feb 02 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)

Want to change : 2/2/2022

Html :

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" (dateInput)="OnDateChange($event)" >
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker touchUi #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

calendar.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar',
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.css']
})
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {
  event : any
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  OnDateChange(event){
    this.event = event
    console.log(this.event.value)
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use datePipe (https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) or formatDate https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Stacky mentioned in the comment you can use [formatDate](https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate) method from common module.

**OR**

You can access input value directly by using template reference variable.
Add template reference variable on input element and pass it as argument to onDateChange callback.

component.html

```
 <input matInput #inputRef [matDatepicker]="picker" (dateInput)="OnDateChange(inputRef)">
```

In component.ts we can read value from input something like this

```
OnDateChange(event:HTMLInputElement){
    this.event = event
    console.log(this.event.value)
 }
```